# how to put argument in a function within windows.open?

Tags: javascript, html

I did a really simple function that opens window in a certain width and height that I adjust. 
My question is the next one : How can you put my width and height argument in my windows.open? I just want to call the function and call the argument to get the exact measurements. Because I will probably have like 3-4 differents windows to open in different sizes...

JAVASCRIPT

```
function ouvrirFenetre(width,height){
    window.open('formulaire.php','mywin','left=20,top=20,width='width',height='height'');
}
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" onclick="ouvrirFenetre(300,200);">My link</a>
```

Comment: Random side-note: I for one set my browser to always open new windows as tabs in the current window, making window size irrelevant ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to concatenate string with variables using `+` sign. Try with:

```
function ouvrirFenetre(width,height){
    window.open('formulaire.php','mywin','left=20,top=20,width=' + width + ',height=' + height);
}
```